# ¿Clase que recibe un genérico con cláusula, puede también implementar una interfaz?

Tags: c#, asp, microsoft

Hola tengo la siguiente clase la cual recibe un genérico que tiene que implementar una interfaz.

[image]

Mi duda es la siguiente: aparte de recibir el genérico de tipo **ITableEntity** quiero que mi clase implemente la interfaz **IAzureTableServices** y no sé si eso se puede y si se puede ¿cuál seria la sintaxis?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! los podes separar con comas.. lo que no estoy seguro, es si no lo toma como un OR, mas que como un AND.. tendrias que hacer un arbolito de cosas para que pases lo que queres si es OR...

Comment: public class AzureTableblabla<T> :  IzureTableServalal where T : ITableEntity

Comment: Gracias ya vi. la sintaxis.